# Strip HTML from JSON In Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

//My JSON Field

```
 [{"image":" <a href=\"http:\/\/docroot.com.dd:8083\/sites\/docroot.com.dd\/files\/catalogues\/2016-09\/images\/Pty%20Prs.compressedjpg_Page1.jpg\">Property Press.compressedjpg_Page1.jpg<\/a>"}]
```

//  Controller am using in my script

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.images = [];
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url    : 'http://docroot.com.dd:8083/catalogue/11/images/json'
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        $scope.images = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.images = response.statusText;
    });
});
```

//output that i got

```
<a href=\"http:\/\/docroot.com.dd:8083\/sites\/docroot.com.dd\/files\/catalogues\/2016-09\/images\/Pty%20Prs.compressedjpg_Page1.jpg\">Property Press.compressedjpg_Page1.jpg<\/a>
```

When i run this application i will get the entire json data with HTML Tag, i need URl of the image from JSON Field. How can i get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanna look into Javascript's `unescape` function:

```
unescape("\"http:\/\/docroot.com.dd:8083\/sites\/docroot.com.dd\/files\/catalogues\/2016-09\/images\/Pty%20Prs.compressedjpg_Page1.jpg\">Property Press.compressedjpg_Page1.jpg<\/a>")
```

Gives:

```
http://docroot.com.dd:8083/sites/docroot.com.dd/files/catalogues/2016-09/images/Pty Prs.compressedjpg_Page1.jpg">Property Press.compressedjpg_Page1.jpg</a>
```

For getting only the URL, you can do this:

```
var xmlString = unescape("\"http:\/\/docroot.com.dd:8083\/sites\/docroot.com.dd\/files\/catalogues\/2016-09\/images\/Pty%20Prs.compressedjpg_Page1.jpg\">Property Press.compressedjpg_Page1.jpg<\/a>"); //Use your variable here. I've used the string directly
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
console.log(doc.firstChild.getAttribute('href')); //Use this to get your href
```

Assuming that the JSON response you have provided is what we're getting, you would want to change your code to so:

```
$http({
    method : "GET",
    url    : 'http://docroot.com.dd:8083/catalogue/11/images/json'
}).then(function mySucces(response) {
    var images = response.data;
    $scope.images = [];
    images.forEach(function(imageUrl) {
        var xmlString = unescape(imageUrl);
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

        $scope.images.push({imageUrl: doc.firstChild.getAttribute('href')});
});
}, function myError(response) {
    $scope.images = response.statusText;
});
```

Comment: toothless 

i need only this url from the JSON Field 

http:\/\/docroot.com.dd:8083\/sites\/docroot.com.dd\/files\/catalogues\/2016-09\/images\/Pty%20Prs.compressedjpg_Page1.jpg
I dont have any idea how to get it

Comment: Updated the answer with your requirement

Comment: ToothLess 
Am using Angularjs , and called JSON data by using http get request , result will save it in a name "Images". and print data by its name "image".

but i don't get data directly inside html tag, is possible to use array name inside 
var xmlString=unescape("images"); ....?

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution. This will give an output of `[{imageUrl: "http://link"},{imageUrl: "http://link"}]`

Comment: Thank you  for your help

Comment: If my answer helped, please upvote and mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

> You can go with the following steps :

Step 1: you can use the regex to extract the url `.*href=(.*)\\">.*`

Output will be : `\"http:\/\/docroot.com.dd:8083\/sites\/docroot.com.dd\/files\/catalogues\/2016-09\/images\/Pty%20Prs.compressedjpg_Page1.jpg`

[Example link](https://regex101.com/r/rZ9gX4/1)

Stem 2: use `unescape` function

Output will be : `""http://docroot.com.dd:8083/sites/docroot.com.dd/files/catalogues/2016-09/images/Pty Prs.compressedjpg_Page1.jpg"`